# Custom Validation Not Triggering ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am learning about custom validation attributes and created a straight forward example for myself but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Here is my Model

```
public class Employee
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [MinLength(2)] [Remote(action: "VerifyNameExists",controller:"Employee")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [LastNameValid] public string? lastname { get; set; }
    public decimal? Salary { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my View

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
<a href="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map">~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map</a>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
@model Employee

<div class="container">
    <h1>Create Employee</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form class="d-grid form-control-sm" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input class="col-sm-4" asp-for="ID" placeholder="ID" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ID" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" asp-for="Name" placeholder="First Name"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" asp-for=lastname placeholder="Last Name"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for=lastname style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br/>
                <input class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"></partial>
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Employee emp) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index",emplist);
}
```

Here is the attribute class added to the last name property of the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVCDemo
{
    public class LastNameValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value == "abc")
            {
                return new ValidationResult("not allowed");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

I read other questions on this site and I dont think I am doing anything different here. But yet...

When I submit the form, there is no validation for the last name as per the attribute

Comment: Do you want the  Remote Validation  for the  lastname ? If not,do you want the client validation ,validate lastname before submit the form ?

Comment: As of now, neither client nor server is working. I would like to test it for both for practice. Also, remote validation (remote attribute) is only on name and not last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server,  you can set a breakpoint at  `if (value == "abc")` you can see it false ,try `value.ToString() == "abc"` :

```
public class LastNameValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "abc")
        {
            return new ValidationResult("not allowed");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

For Client you need to add js, you can read [Custom client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-client-side-validation) to know more.

Below is a  demo, you can refer to it:

LastNameValidAttribute:

```
public class LastNameValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var errorMessage = "not allowed";
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-lastname", errorMessage);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "abc")
        {
            return new ValidationResult("not allowed");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }

        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Modify the js like:

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"></partial>
    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("lastname",
            function (value, element, parameters) {
              
                if (value == "abc") {
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    return true
                }
            });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("lastname");
    </script>

}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank You so much!! I understood the server part but the client side validation looks complex. I will try and go over it.